# SwiftUI MacOS gives Error: Undefined symbol: _main

Tags: macos, swiftui, program-entry-point

I downloaded a SwiftUI source that was built with Xcode Version 12.0 Beta 6, MacOS BigSur version 11.0 Beta. My system was MacOS Catalina, Xcode version 12.0.1.

While compiling, I faced lot of conversion errors one being @main attribute present in AppDelegate.swift

I removed the variable and built the application which resulted in the following error:

Error: Undefined symbol: _main

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the above issue, replace @main attribute in AppDelegate.swift with @NSApplicationMain attribute.